# What are standard practices for developing Coq code in Atom Editor?

Tags: atom-editor, coq, coq-plugin

I wanted to develop some Coq code in Atom. I wanted to be able to check my code line by line as usual just like with CoqIDE or emacs proof general. Is there something like that for atom or how do people develop Coq code in Atom editor?

some links:

https://discuss.atom.io/t/is-there-proof-general-for-coq-in-atom/60862

---

Note: I mostly found syntax hilighting.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not that I know of; the closest you have is [vscoq](https://github.com/siegebell/vscoq/) which even if lagging a bit behind it is on the roadmap to become fully supported again once Coq can speak LSP.

A problem I see with Atom is that its future seems uncertain now that MicroSoft bought GitHub, and indeed, for example it seems to be lacking in LSP support.

Comment: what is LSP support?

Comment: MS = Miscrosoft

Comment: LSP = Language Server Protocol, it is the standard that VsCode is using to communicate with tools and the one we'd like to adopt in Coq.